# C++11 Any class

Tags: c++, c++11, variant-type

This is a polymorphic wrapper capable of holding any type.  (It is loosely based on `boost::any`)

In particular, this is useful when you want to store a heterogeneous collection, such as `vector<Any>`.

### Synopsis

```
string s = ...;
int i = ...;

Any a1 = s;
Any a2 = i;

int j = a2; // ok j now equals i

string t = a1; // ok t now equals s

int k = a1; // runtime exception bad_cast

vector<Any> v;

v.push_back("foo");
v.push_back(42);

const char* s = v[0];
int l = v[1];
```

### Implementation

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
using StorageType = typename decay<typename remove_reference<T>::type>::type;

struct Any
{
    bool is_null() const { return !ptr; }
    bool not_null() const { return ptr; }

    template<typename U> Any(U&& value)
        : ptr(new Derived<StorageType<U>>(forward<U>(value)))
    {

    }

    template<class U> bool is() const
    {
        typedef StorageType<U> T;

        auto derived = dynamic_cast<Derived<T>*> (ptr);

        return derived;
    }

    template<class U>
    StorageType<U>& as()
    {
        typedef StorageType<U> T;

        auto derived = dynamic_cast<Derived<T>*> (ptr);

        if (!derived)
            throw bad_cast();

        return derived->value;
    }

    template<class U>
    operator U()
    {
        return as<StorageType<U>>();
    }

    Any()
        : ptr(nullptr)
    {

    }

    Any(Any& that)
        : ptr(that.clone())
    {

    }

    Any(Any&& that)
        : ptr(that.ptr)
    {
        that.ptr = nullptr;
    }

    Any(const Any& that)
        : ptr(that.clone())
    {

    }

    Any(const Any&& that)
        : ptr(that.clone())
    {

    }

    Any& operator=(const Any& a)
    {
        if (ptr == a.ptr)
            return *this;

        auto old_ptr = ptr;

        ptr = a.clone();

        if (old_ptr)
            delete old_ptr;

        return *this;
    }

    Any& operator=(Any&& a)
    {
        if (ptr == a.ptr)
            return *this;

        swap(ptr, a.ptr);

        return *this;
    }

    ~Any()
    {
        if (ptr)
            delete ptr;
    }

private:
    struct Base
    {
        virtual ~Base() {}

        virtual Base* clone() const = 0;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct Derived : Base
    {
        template<typename U> Derived(U&& value) : value(forward<U>(value)) { }

        T value;

        Base* clone() const { return new Derived<T>(value); }
    };

    Base* clone() const
    {
        if (ptr)
            return ptr->clone();
        else
            return nullptr;
    }

    Base* ptr;
};
```

### Test

```
int main()
{
    Any n;
    assert(n.is_null());

    string s1 = "foo";

    Any a1 = s1;

    assert(a1.not_null());
    assert(a1.is<string>());
    assert(!a1.is<int>());

    Any a2(a1);

    assert(a2.not_null());
    assert(a2.is<string>());
    assert(!a2.is<int>());

    string s2 = a2;

    assert(s1 == s2);
}
```

Comment: This seems not compiling on Visual Studio 2010... anybody tried on VS 2010?

Comment: @DanNiero The C++11 support in Visual Studio (especially the 2010 version) is incomplete. It lacks various features including template aliases (which, I think, the 2012 version lacks as well), so you won't get this code to compile in Visual Studio.

Comment: Does it compile with VS2012?  At least, not on my side.  I've received a lot of compilation errors.

Comment: What's your license on this code?

Comment: @DigitalArchitect: Public domain.  You may use it any way you like without attribution.

Comment: @user1131146accountabandoned, Thanks a lot! If you care at all, I'm including it in an open source project of mine. :) Thanks again.

Comment: @DigitalArchitect:  Which open source project out of interest?

Comment: @user1131146accountabandoned it's unpublished. I'm basically writing out the capabilities of Adobe Flash/AIR in C++, keeping the API exactly the same, then porting over all kinds of stuff like Away3D (which will be basically automated once the framework is finished). Basically something like openframeworks but with an API instantly familiar to many and easy to pick up for others, complete with all the tools/plugins/etc to make any game/app.

Comment: I needed something like boost::any to replace the "*" any type in AS3, but don't want to have any external deps.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
template<class T>
using StorageType = typename decay<typename remove_reference<T>::type>::type;
```

This appears unnecessarily complex: 'decay' already removes a reference. Consider using:

```
template <class T>
using StorageType = typename decay<T>::type;
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> ~Any()
> {
>     if (ptr)
>         delete ptr;
> }
> ```

No need to check for nullptr here because `delete` ignores null pointers.